# limit expression length

Tags: regex, preg-match, expression

I am using the following in a script of mine to verify minutes entered... it allows for numbers and a comma for thousands in the correct format only... however, I would like to add a length restriction as well... I can't seem to do it or I'm just putting itin the wrong spot... here is the code as is with no limit :

```
(!preg_match("#^(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d+))$#",$values['minutes']))
```

I would like to make this at least one with a max of five... the entry is for minutes online per day... well there are only 1440 minutes in a day... if you entered 1,440 which is valid currently that is 5 characters and I want to limit the expression to that...

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

```
preg_match("#^(?:\d{1,3}|1,?\d{3})$#"
```

**Explanation:**

```
^        # Start of string
(?:      # Either match...
 \d{1,3} # a three-digit number
|        # or
 1       # a four digit number that starts with a 1
 ,?      # and may have a thousands separator
 \d{3}   # (and three more digits)
)
$        # End of string
```

The problem is of course that this also allows `1,999`, so you'd still need an extra sanity check. This probably is the better solution.

You *can* also do the range limitation in the regex itself, but that's cumbersome:

```
preg_match("#^(?:1,?440|1,?4[0-3]\d|1,?[0-3]\d{2}|[1-9]\d{1,2}|\d)$#"
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                # Start of string
(?:              # Either match...
 1,?440          # 1440
|                # or  
 1,?4[0-3]\d     # 1400-1439
|                # or
 1,?[0-3]\d{2}   # 1000-1399
|                # or
 [1-9]\d{1,2}    # 10-999
|                # or
 \d              # 0-9
)
$                # End of string
```

Comment: never thought to do it this way - this will work fine - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off just testing the string's length or even the integer value. But just to show that it's possible:

```
preg_match("#^(\d,\d{3}|\d{1,4})$#")
```

Yes, it's very simple, since a four-digit number can only take one of the forms

- one digit, comma, three digits
- four digits